# What topics is my nodelet listening to? (For RGBD6D playback)

Tags: slam, navigation, kinect, rosbag, nodelet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello folks,

Background:

I'm playing around with openni_camera_unstable, hoping to get a two-pass pointcloud-generation system going (in the first pass, I record the image and depth data; in the second, I generate the registered pointclouds; limited hardware on my robot makes this handy).

Question:

If I fire up unstable's openni.launch, I get nice pointclouds exactly like I would expect. What I'd like to do is figure out what topics I need to bag in order to be able to run the point-cloud projection nodelet in a second pass. rosnode list shows /camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb, which is the nodelet doing this work, but rosnode info on that node just lists a bunch of bond topics. The node actually publishing the point clouds is the manager (which I suppose makes sense, as I understand that to be the actual owning process of the various nodelets).

So: how do I figure out which topics my nodelet is subscribing to? (Alternatively, which topics do I need to accomplish what I'm after?)

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10013/what-topics-is-my-nodelet-listening-to?-(for-rgbd6d-playback)/) by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4119 on 2011-05-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To answer your specific use case: you need to bag /camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw, /camera/rgb/image_rect_color, and /camera/rgb/camera_info.

As for the more general question, I have the same frustration. We need nodelet equivalents of rosnode info and rxgraph, but that tooling doesn't exist yet.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JFReuter](https://answers.ros.org/users/831/jfreuter/) on 2011-08-31**:
If you have the bag file playing, run this to get the point cloud: ROS_NAMESPACE=camera rosrun nodelet nodelet standalone openni_camera/point_cloud_xyzrgb

**Comment by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) on 2011-05-26**:
At the bottom of http://www.ros.org/wiki/common (stack containing the nodelet package) there's a "request features" link to create a ticket in the right Trac.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-05-26**:
Thanks for posting; I had, in fact, figured that out by source-code perusal, but failed to post the results. What's the right way to request said features? File a bug? Organize a mob, with signs and patriotic music?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think if you do `rosnode info` on the nodelet manager you'll see the topics all of the nodlets running under it are subscribed to.

---

Originally posted by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) with karma: 2743 on 2011-05-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-05-23**:
Yeah, I did that. No luck. I see a long list of publications (none of which are inter-nodelet; the manager is publishing everything all of the nodelets produce), and a huge number of Bonds, and nothing else.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-05-20**:
I've use it with success for stere_image_proc which is a collection of nodelets and saw subscriptions between nodelets (other than bond). The key was that I did it on the nodelet manager rather than the nodelet.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-05-20**:
Nope (at least, not what I want). I get the "external" plumbing information (the manager is publishing all of the various topics assembled by the nodelets), plus a whole bunch of bond subscriptions. What I want, so to speak, is the "internal" plumbing, showing how the nodelets are connected up.